# How can I buff my Beast?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, changeling-the-lost

I'm currently playing an adventure with four other people where we play Changeling The Lost (NWOD). I created a Beast (Runnerswift) which has been so far underwhelming to play. i blame myself for not grokking fully the interesting choices to make in order to make it good at some things, and especially i want him to be a protector.

As of now, we're in a bit of a pickle, since my beast is the group main theoretical bruiser and we're lacking a bit in muscle. As i chose Summer as my court, i have access to martial related contracts and could develop the PC in interesting ways.

But before spending my hard-earned xps, i'd like to know what you'd recommend regarding `contracts` and `abilities` to have my PC able to throw his weight around, and above all be able to protect his motley...

And if nothing is available... well, i can run *really really* fast when problems arrive ;) so much for protection :p

---

about the dirty buffing, i'm sorry, but that's the term i thought applied (i'm not an english-speaker, originally) and at least i'll have caught your attention ;) It made me laugh though :D

Comment: i was thinking about nwod and changeling - i (partly) posted on meta about this: http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/532/why-does-the-site-say-an-existing-tag-cant-be-created-with-this-low-a-reputation

Comment: This question sounds really dirty to me.

Comment: [Chamois](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chamois_leather)? :)

Comment: By "Swiftfeet," I take it you mean "runnerswift"? What animal is your Beast kith tied to?

Comment: @Jadasc yep, thanks for the correction, i asked the question without the reference under my eyes. I'm linked to felines, and i have the bottled (goblin bargained, so there's a catch) level 5 for Fang & Talon so i'm almost there to transforming into a tiger, except we don't have the stats... another question to ask...

Comment: @samy: The terminology is not incorrect, it just happens to be suggestive choice of phrase

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're set on fighting close, I'd suggest going with Charges and Brawling Dodge; you'll be fighting like Hobbes the tiger, but there's something oddly charming about that. :) One potential tactic would be the use of Goblin's Malignance (Fleeting Summer 2) to draw the ire of potential attackers onto you, and then lead them on a chase that you'll inevitably win, leaving them exhausted in the process.

Comment: wow! Excellent idea! i really like the idea of having a way to get the foes aggro after having pounced on them :) I'll definitely look into that!

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered an emphasis on ranged combat? With your additional Speed and access to `Beast Senses (Fang & Talon ••)`, you might do well with a focus on Firearms or archery or the like. Add the Goblin Contract `Shooter's Bargain` and Fighting Styles to taste.

Comment: No, i never considered ranged combat. In my mind, the runnerswift i was creating was something more like a cheetah, or a puma, so with an emphasis on hit-and-run attacks; i negotiated with Storyteller for my speed to be taken into account when attacking and i decided to buy the lethal mien to be able to connect...  What fighting styles do you think about?

Comment: Did your Storyteller say how he or she would take your Speed into account? Extra dice in the attack, or something else?

Comment: He told me that i could chose between three options, due to a combination of acrobatics with a urban bias (think parkour) and speed; either 3 bonus damage dice, or 3 bonus defense for me, or ignore 3 opponent defense dice. I think i'd always chose to lower the defense since one point of will expended will boost my strength by 4 instead of 3, for damage (beast thingie if i remember well)

Comment: Yeah, lowering a target's Defense is definitely worth it.

Comment: @samy Do you want to put some of those stipulations/intentions into the question to really improve it? :D