# NWOD : stats for animals and edge-cases for transformations in Changeling

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, player-characters, changeling-the-lost

Well, I tried playing with the title to make it as suggestive as "[The Beast-buffing](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/3153/705)", but since this question may have a wider scope let's keep it straight.

---

As I was saying in the other question, I am nearing the moment when my character in a Changeling: the Lost chronicle can change into any feline. The change takes into account what the character is wearing and carrying, and is tremendously powerful. So far so good, I can see many uses for that :)

However, there's a slight problem, in that it's quite hard to find official stats for animals. The white wolf wiki has [a page for felines](http://wiki.white-wolf.com/worldofdarkness/index.php?title=FanBestiary:Cats), but I’d like to be really sure about keeping the game balanced and being able to say "that's the white wolf talking".

Moreover, if I want to branch and also be able to transform into a bird (yes, I’d like my pc to become [Manimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manimal) :) ) I can't seem to find stats for them.

So, the first part of the question is would be is there an official place for animal stats? Source book? Webpage (but I think I’d have found it by now)?

---

Now, there's a special catch in Changeling; since I’m not technically an animal - but rather transforming into one - I’d like to know if there are special modifiers to the base animal stats. Does my tiger form can still understand humans? Does it still benefit from armor gained from stances or summer mantle? What about abilities that have a specialization like Grappling in Brawl?

Obviously some abilities couldn't carry on and I think it's quite easy to rule them in or out : it doesn't make sense for my raven form to drive a car; yes I have 5 dots in driving... but no opposable thumb. However, some others stats/abilities are more complex...

Should we rule it out on a case-by-case basis, or are there common rules for the effect transformation has on the PC ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Descriptions of animals are scattered throughout the World of Darkness line; unfortunately, there is no single sourcebook that covers them all. Many of the ones you want can be found in `Blood of the Wolf`, which is a supplement for **Werewolf: the Forsaken**. The core-line book `Skinchangers` also has some.

As for your second question: the Contract you'll be taking is described on pages 143-4 of `Changeling: The Lost`.

> The creature's Physical Attributes
>   replace the changeling's, but she
>   retains her Social and Mental
>   Attributes. Her Skills also remain the
>   same. ... [S]he can run, fly, or swim
>   normally. While in animal form, the
>   character can speak all human
>   languages she knows, and can also
>   communicate normally with animals of
>   the species she has become.

There's no explicit mention of Contracts; I'd do those on a case by case basis, leaning toward allowing their use while transformed.

Answer (score 2):

About the animals:
The Camarilla, world wide game, (which is offical enough to be hosted on the Whitewolf website) has created a [list of animal stats](http://www.jessilaurn.com/Cam-Global-Addendum/camarillaaddendum-universalappendixbestiary.pdf)

It references a monster manual that should be linked to somewhere [else](http://camarilla.white-wolf.com/MST/) but I can't get the page to load.

Comment: I could not access these links, but I found a less official one for the meantime: [Bestiary](http://nwod.org/wiki/index.php/Bestiary)